# Record Video from mix of the SurfaceView and a some View

Tags: android, screen-capture, video-recording

I have 2 different views in my Fragment - 
 1. a SurfaceView from the ArCore library (I cannot to change it)
 2. and a Frame layout (I draw some objects on it).

So, how I can record video from mix of the both views?

My layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/arFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/arFragment"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/arFragment"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/arFragment"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/arFragment"
            />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

In the current time I have ability to record video only from SurfaceView (by MediaRecorder) or only record the full screen (by MediaProjection). But I do not needed to capture full screen. I need only 2 view.

Comment: have you found solution yet? I have the same problem.

Comment: @peco We are getting screen record via this library https://github.com/pedroSG94/rtmp-rtsp-stream-client-java

Comment: thank you so much i will try it later. I had found easy sollution here: https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/sceneform/video-recording   but  i have problem and can not import VideoRecorder project as module in my application.  I posted question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57779798/add-module-dependency-for-imported-module-shows-blank-screen  If you have time to see it thank you so much. But i will try your suggestion too. Thanks again.

Comment: check this https://gptshubham595.medium.com/unveiling-the-world-of-ar-with-arcore-my-journey-of-exploration-practical-guide-86ac7f54b34